# bars disappears when animation:false in higCharts, showing in chart in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, highcharts

I'm using highCharts, and creating a highChart in fancybox. I want animation off in highCharts. but when I set 'animation: false' the bars in the charts disappears

I don't know what's the problem I've tried many things, if I create highChart without fancybox it creates ok, but fancybox is the requirement. below is my code createHighChart() function create HighChart from the settings that user would set on the page.

```
$.fancybox.open({
            'href' : '#container',
            'titleShow' : false,
            'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            prevEffect      : 'none',
            nextEffect      : 'none',
             afterShow: function(){
                 for(var i=0; i<10000; i++);
                 createHighChart();                     
                 $("#container").show();
             }
        });
```

and createHighChart function:

```
function createHighChart() {
var xData = getXdata();
var yAxisData = getYAxisData();
var t = getInt("threshold_id");
var type = getType();
var backColors = getBackgroundColor();
var isAreaOrLineChart = false;
var customColors = false;
var customPlotOptions =  Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions;

/*uncomment following two lines to provide your custom
 *  colors (an array of colors) for the bars in bar chart*/

/*customColors = true;
customPlotOptions.column.colors = customPlotOptions.bar.colors =
    ['#FF0000', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572'];*/

/***************************change font style****************************/
/*Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        style: {     
            fontSize: '25px',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: 'serif',                
        }
    }
});*/


if(type == "pie") {
    createPieChart();
    return;
}
if(type == "line" || type == "area") {
    isAreaOrLineChart = true;
}
/******************Bar chart specific settings************************/
var barColor = getStr("barcolor_id");
var isMultiColor = false;
if(barColor == "multicolor") {
    barColor = null;
    isMultiColor = true;
}
else if(barColor == "") {
    barColor = null;
}
if(isStacking() == "normal"){
    barColor = isMultiColor = null;
}
var isGrouping = true;
if(getStr("barlayout_id") == "overlap") {
    isGrouping = false;
    barColor = isMultiColor = null;
}

/******************Line chart specific settings************************/
var thickLine = 2;
if(isCheckBoxEnabled("thickline_id")){
    thickLine = 5;
}

/*if(isCheckBoxEnabled("show3d_id")) {
    loadjsfile();
}
else {
    $("#scripto").remove();
    //removejsfile();
}
*/

/*******************Creates the bar chart************************/
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart : {
        //backgroundColor: getStr("chrtbkgndcolor_id"),
        backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
            stops: [
                [0, backColors[0]],
                [1, backColors[1]]
            ]
        },
        renderTo : 'container',
        type : type,
        margin: 75,
        //animation: false,
        options3d: {
            enabled: isCheckBoxEnabled("show3d_id") && !isAreaOrLineChart,
            alpha: 10,
            beta: 10,
            depth: 50,
            viewDistance: 25
        },
        borderColor: '#A9A9A9',
        borderRadius: isRoundCorner(),
        borderWidth: isBorder(),

        width: getInt("width_id"),
        height: getInt("height_id")
    },
    title : {
        text : getStr("title_id"),
        style: {

            fontWeight: getFontWeight("fonttypetitle_id"),
            fontStyle: getFontStyle("fonttypetitle_id")
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: getStr("subtitle_id"),
        style: {
            fontWeight: getFontWeight("fonttypetitle_id"),
            fontStyle: getFontStyle("fonttypetitle_id")
        }
    },
     tooltip: {
            enabled: isCheckBoxEnabled("tooltip_id")
     },
     credits: {
            text: getStr("source_id"),
            href: '#'
     },
     legend: {
            enabled: isCheckBoxEnabled("legend_id"),              
        },
    xAxis : {

        title:{ 
            text: getStr("xtitle_id"),
            style: {
                fontWeight: getFontWeight("fonttypetitle_id"),
                fontStyle: getFontStyle("fonttypetitle_id")
            }
            },
        categories : xData,
        labels: {
            rotation: getRotation(),
            style: {
                 fontWeight: getFontWeight("fonttypelabel_id"),
                 fontStyle: getFontStyle("fonttypelabel_id")
            }
        },            

        /*below two lines are for x-axis line, it is not working
         * due to inclusion of the 3D charts library 
         * (namely this line:
         *  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>) 
         *  in the include/ChartGoLiteJSFiles.jsp */
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#FF0000',      

        gridLineWidth: false         
    },
    yAxis :  
    {
        //lineWidth: 20,
        min: getMinMaxY("min_yaxis_id"),
        max: getMinMaxY("max_yaxis_id"), 
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: t,
            dashStyle: 'shortdash',          
            id: 'plotline-1'
        }],

        title : {
            text : getStr("ytitle_id"),
            style: {
                fontWeight: getFontWeight("fonttypetitle_id"),
                fontStyle: getFontStyle("fonttypetitle_id")
            }
        },
        labels: {               
            style: {
                 fontWeight: getFontWeight("fonttypelabel_id"),
                 fontStyle: getFontStyle("fonttypelabel_id")
            }
        },  
        /*below two lines are for x-axis line, it is not working
         * due to inclusion of the 3D charts library 
         * (namely this line:
         *  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>) 
         *  in the include/ChartGoLiteJSFiles.jsp */
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#FF0000',
        gridLineColor: '#197F07',
        gridLineWidth: isCheckBoxEnabled("gridlines_id")
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation:  false,//this is not working right
            shadow: isShadow(),
            color: barColor,
            //colorByPoint: isMultiColor || customColors,
            stacking: isStacking(),
            marker: {
                enabled: isCheckBoxEnabled("shape_id")
            },
            lineWidth: thickLine
        }, 
        column: {           
            //animation: false,
             colorByPoint: isMultiColor || customColors,
             depth: 25,  
             grouping: isGrouping
        },    
        bar: {
            colorByPoint: isMultiColor || customColors,
        },

    },
    series : yAxisData      
});
chart.container.onclick = isCheckBoxEnabled("mouse_interaction_id");
if(t == 0)
    chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('plotline-1');
```

}

Comment: Can you recreate your chart as live demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: How can I add fancybox in jsfiddle?

Comment: Generally we need a live demo, so please supply in any environment which allows to check / edit code.